# Get position of an item within a ListView?

Tags: java, android

How would one find the position of a specific item within a ListView? (Populated by SimpleCursorAdapter).

The reason I ask: The listview is set to singleChoice mode. When the user closes and reopens the app, I'd like the user's selection to be remembered.

The way I've done it so far is when the user clicks on an item, the ID of the chosen item is saved to preferences. What I need to learn is how to reselect the item in the activity's onCreate method once it's been repopulated.

My code for saving the selected item's ID:

```
    @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Cursor c = (Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    selectedItem = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
}
```

(I've tried googling, but only seem to find how to get the position of the *selected* item)

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should try

```
//SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
final int position = adapter.getCursor().getPosition();
```

**API Docs:**

```
public abstract int getPosition ()
```

**Since: API Level 1**

> Returns the current position of the
>   cursor in the row set. The value is
>   zero-based. When the row set is first
>   returned the cursor will be at positon
>   -1, which is before the first row. After the last row is returned another
>   call to `next()` will leave the cursor
>   past the last entry, at a position of
>   `count()`.

**Returns**
the current cursor position.

**Update**

To get an item's position based on the id used by the adapter:

```
private int getItemPositionByAdapterId(final long id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++)
    {
        if (adapter.getItemId(i) == id)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

To get an item's position based on the underlying object's properties (member values)

```
//here i use `id`, which i assume is a member of a `MyObject` class, 
//and this class is used to represent the data of the items inside your list:
private int getItemPositionByObjectId(final long id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++)
    {
        if (((MyObject)adapter.getItem(i)).getId() == id)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But how would I look up the position of an item, given an ID?

Comment: (sorry, I hope I'm not being overly dense!!)

Comment: Don't worry about it. You mean an id which is a member of the underlying object you render, or the id used by the adapter (in case they are not the same)? anyway, i just updated the answer, maybe it covers what you need

Comment: I think I have some learning to do, because I don't think I'm after either one of those IDs (LOL!) I wanted the position of the item given its "_id" field in the sqlite db. But I'm guessing my approach isn't a good one, I'll have to think long and hard about your suggestions, thanks!

Comment: If you keep changing your question, none of the answers will ever be approved, and actually good answers get deprecated (wrong!) :( You should better ask ask a new question, and link this one to it. On the other hand: what is the structure of the `listview` item's data (the java class of the data you get from the database)? Knowing that would be easier to help you out with this question too.

Comment: Apologies for that! Regarding your question, I'm very confused. I haven't written one, (a class for the listview's item datatype) if that answers it? but I think my code is a bit of a hack, effectively just uses the Cursor within the overridden bindView method of my custom SimpleCursorAdapter. I should probably start a new question about now lol. Thanks for your help, (and everyone else's as well, I think I can just about muddle through for now! Plenty to think about here.)

Answer (score 3):

I do this straightforward in my own app:

```
long lastItem = prefs.getLong(getPreferenceName(), -1);
if (lastItem >= 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        if (lastItem == cursor.getLong(0)) {
            spinner.setSelection(cursor.getPosition());
            break;
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

Spinner is populated with the cursor's contents, so I just look through them and compare with the selected item id. In your case that would be a ListView.

Comment: That's the effect I was looking for! I was hoping to find a way round needing to iterate through all the items, but perhaps it's unavoidable. Thanks

Comment: great piece of code. really helped without a place to modify thanks

Comment: This might be the fastest solution, cause it works directly with the backing data, not the view or adapter.

Answer (score 1):

When you say, "...reselecting the item in the activity's onCreate method...", do you mean that when the user returns to the ListView activity, whatever item was previously chosen, is now currently at the top of the screen (assuming enough items appear in the list below it)?

If so, then from onListItemClick, you should also make an effort to save the value of `position`, since it tells you the position in the list of the selected item.  This would allow you to not need to reverse-lookup the position from the `_id`.

Or is that for some reason not an option for your purposes?  Do you really need to instead figure out the position from the `_id`?

Comment: Thane, thank you, yes that's exactly what I meant. I didn't think using the position was a good idea, but Perhaps I'll resort to that after all.