# Getting Row position in android listview

Tags: android

Hi this may sound like a silly question but it has been disturbing me for a few days and I haven't found the answer on the internet. In android Listview without overriding the onItemclick method is there any other way I can get the position of a row.

Comment: Yes there are different ways. When do you wanna get the position?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5685008/735675

Comment: thanks lazy ninja i want to get the position when i click on a listview button as you know this disables the onitemclick option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use setTag()/getTag() methods for getting the position of the item. In the getView() method of the list adapter set position of the item as the tag of the row items(in your case button) using **setTag("position")** method.
When the button in any row is clicked the onClick() method will be called for that button and in the onClick() method you can use **getTag()** method to get the position. Use same method as the onClick routine for all the rows button.

sample code: List item could be something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="117dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grad"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
```

getView() method could be something like this:

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    ...
    button.setTag(position);
    ...
}
```

onClick routine could be something like this:

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    String tag = v.getTag().toString();
    if(tag != null) {
         int position = Integer.parseInt(tag);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: hi i'm using a simplecursoradapter to bind this listview i need the position to be able to capture the data in that row that isn't bound to some of the textboxes the solution you've given me is currently working not its giving the error illegalstateexception  could you help me further